# apache/flask - when uploading file, requests are beeing qued, server unresponsive & memory gets high

Tags: python, apache, flask

I'm running Flask on Apache with mod_wsgi, every time a file get uploaded, the response time of the server worses, and my memory goes over 100% to swap.

This below is the whole code that handles my upload

```
@app.route(sApiRoute + '/f/upload', methods=['POST'])
@hasToken
def pbFileUpload(token=None,**kwargs):
    def log_time(start_dt=None,start_time=None,doc=None):
       end_time = None
       if start_time is not None:
          end_time = str(time.time()-start_time)

       if end_time is not None and end_time > str(0.3):
          pblog.warning("Upload with long response time. Start: "+str(start_dt)+ "Duration: "+str(end_time)+" \nUploader: " + token["id_user"] + " \nDoc info: " + str(doc))

    import time
    start_time = time.time()
    start_dt = current_datetime()


    # parse path
    path = getUploadPath(request.json, None, token)
    if not path:
        return r404()
    # Get the name of the uploaded file
    filename = request.json["name"]
    filename =     filename.replace("$c$","č").replace("$c2$","ć").replace("$z$","ž").replace("$s$","š").replace("$d$","đ").replace("$C$","Č").replace("$C2$","Ć").replace("$Z$","Ž").replace("$S$","Š").replace("$D$","Đ")
    rawfile = request.json["data"]
    header, data = rawfile.split(',')
    # convert data
    import base64
    recoveredfile = base64.decodebytes(bytes(data, 'UTF-8'))
    # write data
    import uuid
    # leave file name as is
    if request.json.get("leaveName"):
        generatedfilename = filename
        leaveName = True
    else:
        generatedfilename = str(uuid.uuid1())
        leaveName = False
    # use of ftp to save files
    if 'ftp.' in path.lower():
        putFileToFtp(path, filename, generatedfilename, recoveredfile)

    # classic directory structure
    else:
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            try:
                os.mkdir(path)
            except Exception as e:
                pblog.warning(str(e),exc_info=1)
                return jsonify(data={"status":False,"msg":"Path not found"})

        while os.path.exists(os.path.join(path, generatedfilename)) and not     leaveName:
            generatedfilename = str(uuid.uuid1())
        with open(os.path.join(path, generatedfilename), "wb") as out_file:
            out_file.write(recoveredfile)
        out_file.close()

    # send to document system
    if request.json.get("dataRec"):
        db = DBStore.getDB(token["current_company_id"])
        dataRec = request.json.get("dataRec")
        dataRec["idext"] = generatedfilename
        rtd = DocumentCls.getIdByIdent(dataRec["IdDocumentType"],db)
        if rtd and rtd!=[]:
            if rtd.get("Id"):
                dataRec["IdDocumentType"] = rtd["Id"]
        r = DocumentCls.saveDocument(dataRec,request.json.get("username"),db)
        log_time(start_dt,start_time,dataRec)
        return jsonify(data={"version":     r,"generatedfilename":generatedfilename},**kwargs)
    else:
        log_time(start_dt,start_time,generatedfilename)
        return jsonify(data={"filename": filename, "generatedfilename":     generatedfilename},**kwargs)
```